# Service Leaked Error

Tags: java, android, webview

hi guys im getting this error in my log cat and i dont know how to fix..

```
android.app.ServiceConnectionLeaked: Activity com.example.harrops.h20droidapp.webstreamsListview has leaked ServiceConnection azy@236e1451 that was originally bound here
```

i have a list view that when an item is clicked it opens a webview for that item. i also have a webclient set up for this as i need the webpage have its own custom loading dialog and also if it opens certain links it will open them in the factory browser. any help or incite into what is going on would be greatly appreciated

this is my webstreamsListview

```
@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    wv.saveState(outState);
}


@Override
protected void onCreate(final Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_webstreams_listview);


    if (savedInstanceState == null) {


        mAdView = (AdView) findViewById(R.id.webstreams_adview);
        mAdView2 = (AdView) findViewById(R.id.webstreams_adview1);

        lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lvWebstreamingSites);
        lv.setScrollbarFadingEnabled(false);
        lv.setAdapter(new webStreamsAdapter(this));
        wv = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.wvWebStreamingSites);


        final AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder()
                .addTestDevice(AdRequest.DEVICE_ID_EMULATOR)
                .build();
        mAdView.loadAd(adRequest);


        lv.setOnItemClickListener(new CastingOnitemListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                switch (position) {


                    case 0:


                        wv.setScrollbarFadingEnabled(false);

                        wv.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
                        wv.setLayerType(View.LAYER_TYPE_SOFTWARE, null);
                        wv.getSettings().setRenderPriority(WebSettings.RenderPriority.NORMAL);
                        wv.getSettings().setLoadsImagesAutomatically(true);
                        wv.getSettings().setCacheMode(WebSettings.LOAD_DEFAULT);

                        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 19) {
                            // chromium, enable hardware acceleration
                            wv.setLayerType(View.LAYER_TYPE_HARDWARE, null);
                        } else {
                            // older android version, disable hardware acceleration
                            wv.setLayerType(View.LAYER_TYPE_SOFTWARE, null);
                        }
                        wv.canGoBackOrForward(1);
                        wv.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
                        wv.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);
                        wv.setScrollBarStyle(View.SCROLLBARS_INSIDE_OVERLAY);


                        wv.setPadding(0, 0, 0, 0);

                        wv.setWebViewClient(new webclient1(dialog, c));


                        wv.loadUrl(MY URL);

                        break;
```

and this is my webclient class

```
public class webclient1 extends WebViewClient {


View v;
ProgressDialog dg;

public webclient1(ProgressDialog dialog, Context c) {
    this.dg = dialog;


    dg = new ProgressDialog(c,R.style.CustomDialog);
   dg.setTitle("H20 its an app thing ...");
    dg.setIcon(R.drawable.h20_dialog_logo);
    dg.setMessage("Please wait...");

}

@Override
public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView webView, String urlNewString) {
   webView.getSettings().setSupportMultipleWindows(true);

        webView.getContext().startActivity(
                new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(urlNewString)));
        return true;



}



@Override
public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon) {
    view.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    dg.show();
}

@Override
public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
    view.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    dg.dismiss();
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

ok guys i think it was because of my custom webclient still passing services after the webview was closed this is how ive fixed it.

i did this void method in my webstreamslistview class which clears everything once the webpage is destroyed

```
@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
super.onDestroy();

wv.removeAllViews();
wv.clearHistory();
wv.clearCache(true);
wv.clearView();
wv.destroy();
wv= null;
```

}